# by the time: what tense to use

Tags: tense

I'd like to state a general fact. What tense should I use for the main clause and for the by-the-time-clause?

> Generally speaking, most of them have had sex by the time they reach the eleventh grade.

> Generally speaking, most of them had had sex by the time they reached the eleventh grade.

> Generally speaking, most of them will have had sex by the time they reach the eleventh grade.

I think the first sentence is a present fact, the second is a past fact, and the third is a future fact.

I'd like to indicate this is a permanent fact, not about the past, nor the future. So I start with "generally speaking". But I'm afraid the first sentence is ungrammatical, because I think if I use the present tense for the by-the-time-clause, I should use the future tense for the main clause.

---

Here is another example:

Every day, by the time we get home from school, mom has prepared the dinner.

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version is fine as a general statement about young people.

The second is appropriate only when talking about a particular group studied for research purposes in the past.

The third is a prediction.